# What is this metallic object with teeth in mouth, screw to tighten and a handle?

Tags: united-kingdom, identification

What is this metallic object with teeth in mouth, screw to tighten and a handle? I can't find out anything about it.

[image: Metallic object with teeth in mouth, screw to tighten and a handle]

Comment: Clearly an adjustable widget of some kind ;) Where did you find it?

Comment: Provenance helps; any marks or trademarks? Dimensions?  Materials? Obviously intended to hold something - perhaps maize?

Comment: Is the pearlescent bit in the background a handle? If so, is it permanently attached? Looks like a kitchen utensil of some kind.

Answer (score 30):

A similar item was sold at an auction site [here](https://auction.catawiki.com/kavels/10083129-wild-meat-clamp-with-silver-handle-chicken-leg-or-leg-of-lamb-holder-france-19th-century). [image]

The item listed on that site is called a 'wild meat clamp' and is described as made to hold chicken legs or leg-of-lamb.

The French term *Manche a Gigot* (Thanks @LangLangC) will lead to many more examples [in a search](https://www.google.com/search?q=manche%20a%20gigot&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjodfKueHiAhUnsVQKHUkbA404ChD8BQgKKAE&biw=1366&bih=625&dpr=1).

Comment: Another superb answer - I strongly suspected that was the case, but I couldn't find the evidence to prove it. Well done.

Comment: What Mark said. I wouldn't dare to put the search words into the engine though ;) – Now: when was this style introduced or current? Is the design limited to tag:UK? Material(s)?

Comment: And lacking the vocab for this: how to translate this? Fer à Gigot, it seems. That seems to give 'straighter' results.

Comment: Great find! I tried and failed abysmally :)

Comment: @LangLangC: *Gigot* refers to a leg of lamb, mutton, or venison as a separate cut of meat.  *Manche* means "handle" in this context, and *fer* means "iron" (as in a soldering iron, clothes iron, tire iron, etc.)  So *manche à gigot* = "leg-of-lamb handle" and *fer à gigot* =  "leg-of-lamb iron".  Amusingly, *manche* can also mean "sleeve", and [gigot sleeves](http://www.thefashionhistorian.com/2011/03/gigot-sleeves.html) are also a thing.